# Agregar Array de Objetos en un schema mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo este esquema:

```
  const AsientoSchema = new Schema({
    numero: Number,
    fecha: Date,
    cuenta: Array,
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('asientos', AsientoSchema);
```

Al campo cuenta del modelo anterior tengo que enviar un Array de Objetos:

```
const datos = [{ nombre: "bco", importe: 25000 }, { nombre: "proov", importe: 95009 }];
```

Tengo un formulario para enviar los datos. Con la fecha y el número no tengo problemas. El problema es que no se como enviar el Array de Objetos.

Esta es la ruta en Express:

```
router.post('/crear-asiento', async (req, res, next) => {
    const nvo_asiento = new Asiento(req.body);

    await nvo_asiento.save(); /
    res.redirect('/crear-asiento');
});
```

Este es el formulario para enviar los valores:

```
<form action="/crear-asiento" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="numero">
        <input type="date" name="fecha">       
        <button type="submit" >crear asiento</button>   
</form>
```

He intentado mandarlo como String pero luego no puedo convertirlo o usarlo como objeto desde el schema. Mi duda es cómo puedo enviarlo junto con los datos del formulario. Gracias

Comment: No entiendo si tu problema es en la interfaz o en el backend.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera puede hacer el flujo de lo que necesitas

```
function saveForm (form) {
    let {numero, fecha, cuentas} = form
    let structForm = {
        numero: numero,
        fecha: fecha,
        cuenta: cuentas
    }
    return structForm
}

router.post('/crear-asiento', async (req, res, next) => {
    const nvo_asiento = new Asiento(saveForm(req.body));

    await nvo_asiento.save(); /
    res.redirect('/crear-asiento');
});

<form action="/crear-asiento" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="numero">
        <input type="date" name="fecha">       
        <input type="text" name="cuentas[0]['nombre']['bco']">
        <input type="text" name="cuentas[0]['importe']['25000']">
        .
        .
        .
        <button type="submit" >crear asiento</button>   
</form>
```